# Can high energy photons be used to accelerate particles?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, photons, particle-accelerators

So I know that particle accelerators use electromagnets to accelerate particles. However, since photons can be used to recoil particles (such as in Compton scattering), is it possible to use high energy photons with very short wavelengths to accelerate particles?

Comment: try looking up "wakefield accelerator"

Comment: have a look https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_acceleration

Comment: So not a laser wakefield mechanism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not easy, but definitely possible, for free charged particles. Scattering of a photon off of an electron at rest can be most easily understood in the center-of-mass frame with zero total momentum. The electron moves toward the photon slowly, and the photon moves toward the electron at, well, the speed of light. They scatter off eachother, and the photon ends up with the same wavelength/momentum magnitude, and so does the electron, but in a new random direction. But in the rest frame, photons will be preferentially absorbed from the beam and re-emitted in some other direction, so your charged particle will feel a small net force pushing on it from the beam's direction. This is called the "radiation pressure on free electrons"
http://www.jetp.ras.ru/cgi-bin/dn/e_034_01_0059.pdf
I think the main reason it isn't useful is that the cross section for this kind of scattering is so small - a powerful laser beam is needed and most of it will be wasted.

But light is used to accelerate atoms all the time in experiments called atomic fountains:
The original atomic fountain just hit a cloud of cold atoms with resonant photons from a laser pulse pointing upward. Same concept as before - light being absorbed from the beam and emitted in a random direction - but now the cross section is enhanced by a resonance with the electronic energy levels.
https://journals-aps-org.libproxy.berkeley.edu/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.63.612
Modern atomic fountains use more complex techniques where the photon isn't re-emitted in a random direction, but into another laser beam pointing in the opposite direction, so there isnt *any* random component to the final motion.
https://par.nsf.gov/servlets/purl/10096353
these techniques aren't used to accelerate atoms (or ions - why not?) to high energies... because why would you? - RF cavities are working just fine.

A third and final option for neutral atoms is moving optical tweezers
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_tweezers
Atoms are either repelled or attracted to regions with higher amplitude oscillating electric fields depending on whether the frequency is below or above one of their atomic transitions. I believe this has been proposed as a source of acceleration for atoms - make an optical tweezer trap where atoms are confined in the focus of a laser beam where the light is strongest - and move that focus to accelerate the atoms. Like with fountains - this is for giving atoms a well-defined velocity, not for accelerating them relativistically.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to model the operation of the (now-decommissioned) main beamline at SLAC in this way.

The beamline was a microwave waveguide two miles long which was driven by synchronous microwave oscillators along its length so as to set up a continuous traveling wave stretching all the way from the electron gun to the experiment hall 10,000 feet distant.

Its electrical characteristics (capacitance and inductance per foot) were carefully designed to yield a propagation speed of the microwave photons inside the waveguide ever so slightly less than the speed of light.

Electrons were then shot into the head end of the beamline at better than 0.99c and formed into bunches that fit between the peaks of the microwave beam. The electron bunches then "surfed" the microwave beam (consisting of photons) all the way to the experiment hall, absorbing energy from it and emerging with gigavolt energies.